# laravel 5.0 save data in pivot table that is used as a model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am building a custom templating system for my newsletters where you can add pre defined Blocks to a newsletter. These will be stored as serialized html in my Blocks table.

So a newsletter can have many blocks and a block can have many newsletters so we got a many-to-many relation here. (One block also has a certain amount of BlockItems)

Now I am trying to use the newsletters_blocks pivot table as a seperate model to put an other relation on this pivot table. So I can store the content in that new table. This way the blocks and blocks_items table are pre defined and will stay untouched and it will be easy to add new ones in the future.

My database looks like this:
[image: relations]

My models look like this:

Newsletter Model:

```
class Newsletter extends Model
{
    public function blocks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Block', 'blocks', 'newsletter_id', 'blocks_id')
            ->withPivot(
                'block_order',
                'block_item_content_id'
            )
            ->as('block_item_content')
            ->using(BlockNewsletterPivot::class);
    }
}
```

Block Model:

```
class Block extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blocks';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'image_thumbnail', 'image', 'html'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function newsletter()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Newsletter');
    }

    public function blockItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\BlockItem');
    }
}
```

BlockItem Model:

```
class BlockItem extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blocks_items';

    protected $fillable = ['block_id', 'item_type', 'html_key'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function block()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Block');
    }
}
```

The pivot table newsletters_blocks Model

```
class NewsletterBlockPivot extends Pivot
{
    public function blockItemContent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BlockItemContent::class);
    }
}
```

BlockItemContent Model:

```
class BlockItemContent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'block_item_content';

    protected $fillable = ['item_type', 'html_key', 'content', 'properties'];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Now if I want to access the content field of the block_item_content table I can do this like so:

```
 $newsletter->newsletters_blocks->blockItemContent->content
```

But now I am trying to link a block to a newsletter but I am not sure how I can do this. To be honest I am not even sure if it's possible what I am trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to access:

`$newsletter->newsletters_blocks->blockItemContent->content`

**Let's analyse this:**

**First part**

`$newsletter->newsletters_blocks`

In your `Newsletter` Model you have defined the many to many relationship with `blocks` table using the function `blocks()` inside the function:

`$this->belongsToMany('Block', 'blocks', 'newsletter_id', 'blocks_id')` should be something like:

`$this->belongsToMany(Block::class, ...everything else should be fine if correct...)`

So, you can access many blocks of one newsletter as below:

`$newsletter->blocks`

but not `$newsletter->newsletters_blocks`

**Now, Second part**

let's go forward: `$newsletter->blocks->blockItemContent`

What does it mean? if `$newsletter->blocks` means many blocks, then how can we access `blockItemContent` of many blocks all at once?
you have to do something like:

```
foreach($newsletter->blocks as $block){
  dump($block->blockItemContent->content);//here it is
}
```

This is how it should work if all your define relationships are correct and all the database columns and foreign keys are correct. Best of luck.

Comment: I am not trying to access any data actually I am trying to store data.